# Hide scrollbar in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have an app with a ScrollView, and I don't want the scrollbar to appear on the screen. How can I hide the scrollbar in a ScrollView while making sure scrolling still works?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove scroll bar track from ScrollView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273335/remove-scroll-bar-track-from-scrollview-in-android)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

In Java add this code:

```
myScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
myScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

In XML add following attribute to your ScrollView:

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainScroll"
android:scrollbars="none" <!-- line to be added -->
>
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i handle onScrollChanged event?

Comment: See this question it may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263053/android-scrollview-onscrollchanged

Comment: scroll functionality does NOT work with this solution

Comment: android:scrollbarSize="0dp"

Comment: Using scrollbars="none" doesn't allow the user to scroll sometimes

Answer (score 42):

This will hide the Scroll bar stick but scroll bar is not disable

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null"

android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"
```

This will disable the scroll bar

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Comment: `android:scrollbars="none"` does not disable scrollbars.you can scroll but  just hides ` scrollview stick`

Answer (score 17):

In XML set `android:scrollbars="none"`

Comment: can you tell me how can i handle onScrollChanged event?

Comment: scroll functionality does NOT work with this solution

Comment: Do you know why this makes the view NOT scrollable?

Answer (score 9):

Try this, it is also working...

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null"
```

or

```
android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"
```

Answer (score 5):

In my experience,

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null"
```

can cause **NullPointerException** in older devices. Use this instead:

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent"
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

you have to try the following solutions

```
    android:scrollbars="none"
```

OR

```
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null"
    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"
```

OR  Change color of scrollBars to hide them

```
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 3):

For hiding a vertical scrollbar, do this in the XML:

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null"
```

And for Hiding horizontal scrollbar do this :

```
android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"
```

The above lines of codes will work if you want to hide the scrollbar without disabling it.

And for disabling a scrollbar, write this:

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Answer (score 2):

In the XML layout, add this property:

```
android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Now the scroll does not work anymore if u set `android:scrollbars="none"`

I have solved the problem with

```
  android:scrollbars="vertical" // or horizontal
```

and setting its size to 0 dp

```
  android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin Solution

If you need to do this programmatically, you can set either one or both of:

```
scrollView.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false
scrollView.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
```

If you'll be applying both regularly, try adding this extension

```
fun ScrollView.noScrollbars() {
    isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false
    isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
}
```

To easily allow switching, you can add an optional boolean

```
fun ScrollView.noScrollbars(hide: Boolean = true) {
    isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = !hide
    isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = !hide
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are making "custom" HorizontalScrollView then you should set those properties in code like so

`this.scrollBarSize = 0
this.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false`

That is the only way I got mine to work.