# ViewPort is not Working on Android

Tags: android, html

I'm testing html file on android tabs and phones. Viewport for different resolutions 
I used meta ViewPort:

> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width , target-densityDpi=device-dpi , user-scalable = no , initial-scale=.51,maximum-scale=0.51,minimum-scale=0.51"/>
> ```

but its not working means not scaling my BG image.

I tried it with it also:

```
<meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width;target-densityDpi=device-dpi ; user-scalable = no ;initial-scale=.51;maximum-scale=0.51;minimum-scale=0.51"/>
```

the only difference is ';' but on it logcat shows Viewport ignored

I don't understand why this happening

This is my css file:

```
body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0;

}

div { width: 1280px; height: 670px; }
home {

background-image: url('../images/abc_title.png');
width: 1280px;
height: 670px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
abc_slide {

position: relative; background : transparent;
width: 129px;
height: 76px;
background: transparent; width : 129px; height : 76px;
margin-top: 80px;
margin-left: 80px;
        border: thin;

}
song_slide {

position: relative;
background: transparent;
margin-top: 80px;
margin-left: 80px; width : 129px;
height: 76px;
width: 129px;
    border: thin;

}
```

HTML:

[image]

With these settings i see follwing situation on my tab 2 7:

[image]

after adding no-repeat scrolls are already there.

Comment: Which version of Android ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What are your CSS styles for the background?

Comment: 2.2 and running on 4.0.1

Comment: @Stan i want to use Viewport for multiple resolution for android devices and iphone devices

Comment: @User95280, that's obvious, but your main concern is about background. If you want background to scale, use `background-size: cover;`.

Comment: @Stan I added an image from where you can understand what question is basically

Comment: @User95280, from your screenshot it's not clear what image do we see. If it's in div with id "home", then it lacks `no-repeat` in CSS. You have `no-repeat` for `body` but I don't see any background image for the body. Fix this and try `background-size: cover` as I suggested.

Comment: <div id='home'> and home {

background-image: url('../images/abc_title.png');
width: 1280px;
height: 670px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26867/discussion-between-user95280-and-stan)

Comment: http://github.hubspot.com/select/docs/welcome/

Comment: https://github.com/derekpcollins/jquery-custom-select-menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, comma is the correct delimiter in the content attribute, like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=.51, maximum-scale=0.51, minimum-scale=0.51"/>
```

You also had some extra spaces in there.  I would hope the WebKit implementation on Android would tolerate that, but be careful anyway.  :)

By default, a Worklight-generated Android environment only has `normalScreens` enabled.  I suspect, by the width/height numbers you show and that it is a tablet, that you have a "large screen", in Android-speak.  Please check the `AndroidManifest.xml` for the following section:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:anyDensity="false"
    />
```

Adjust as necessary according to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

You can also set `android:scrollbars="none"` in the `WebView` XML element in `AndroidManifest.xml`.  See [second answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273335/remove-scroll-bar-track-from-scrollview-in-android).

Comment: Another good question to read:  [Making Sense of Android meta-viewport scaling: What am I missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893045/making-sense-of-android-meta-viewport-scaling-what-am-i-missing?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use viewport in webView you need to enable [setUseWideViewport](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUseWideViewPort(boolean)) and [setLoadWithOverviewMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setLoadWithOverviewMode(boolean)) or else WebView is neglect the meta viewport tag.

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Refer: [Pixel perfect UI in the WebView](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/pixelperfect)