# Android ScrollView how to remove larger scroll indicator on scroll bar with arrows appear above smaller bar

Tags: android, scrollview

In android scroll bar there seem to be an additional indicator appearing top of small scroll indicator with up down arrows, is it possible to remove this additional larger scroll indicator. I might have missed the api method in ScrollView.

```
setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)
```

But I do not want to remove small scroll indicator appearing.

this also didn't remove the additional larger indicator with arrows

[image: Larger indicator with arrows]

Thank you :)

Comment: Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273335/remove-scroll-bar-track-from-scrollview-in-android

Comment: view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY) does not help either. I want to keep small scroll bar but want to remove additional scroll indicator with up down arrows that appear on scroll

Answer (score 0):

To remove scrollbar (indicator) add this in xml layout file

```
android:scrollbars="none"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
```

Fore more about scrollview visit [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3ascrollbars)

Comment: Actually I want to keep small scroll indicator, I want to remove additional scroll indicator that appear with up down arrows when scroll view is large.

Comment: After seen your screenshot i can say that its accrue due to android theme or build version is older...

Comment: actually i have the latest android on my HTC one. There's two inidicators appearing, one is slightly smaller usual and when we scroll further there's this additional one coming up. But some other apps installed from Google Play doesn't have this I installed on my android device

Comment: you mean layout xml file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45563/discussion-between-blacktiger-and-tharindu-madushanka)

Comment: Mm. Haven't found a solution yet on chat :(